# Adding a blank line in a specific position in an unordered list with jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, html-lists

I have an UL created through PHP and jQuery UI that looks like this:

```
<ul id="ml_organize">
<li id="il1" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl1" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('1')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">MAS-NTWKBAYKIT</span><span class="org_desc">FLOOR MNTG HARDWARE KIT (NTWK)</span></li>
<li id="il13" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl2" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('2')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">ESDSTRAP</span><span class="org_desc">ADJ ELASTIC 63070</span></li>
<li id="il12" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl3" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('3')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">ESDLABEL</span><span class="org_desc">GREEN .75" X 1.75" ESD LABEL</span></li>
<li id="il11" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl4" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('4')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">SPT6224</span><span class="org_desc">SPLIT TUBE 5/8" X 24" GRAY</span></li>

<li id="il10" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl5" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('5')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">SAF2502</span><span class="org_desc">FRAMING CLIP ASSM AUX CHNL 5/8</span></li>
<li id="il9" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl6" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('6')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">TR53</span><span class="org_desc">5/8-11 THREADED ROD X  24.0"</span></li>
<li id="il8" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl7" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('7')";></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">CJB6302C</span><span class="org_desc">CLIP J-BOLT ASSM FOR 2"CR/FC</span></li>
<li id="il7" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl8" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('8')";></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">RFCH702</span><span class="org_desc">HEAVY HARDWARES(PAIR) 2.0" STGR</span></li>
<li id="il6" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl9" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('9')";></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">FBM26CB</span><span class="org_desc">FLR BASE MLDINGX26" (CB VINYL)</span></li>

<li id="il5" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl10" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('10')";></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">AFC2202DG</span><span class="org_desc">AUX CHANNEL, 4Â¿</span></li>
<li id="il4" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl11" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('11')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">601343874</span><span class="org_desc">UNI-STRUT KIT - ED8C509-50 G9 EQUIVALENT</span></li>
<li id="il3" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl12" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('12')";></span><span class="org_qty">4</span><span class="org_partno">ISS888</span><span class="org_desc">INSUL STRIP FOR BAYS-42" LONG</span></li>
<li id="il2" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl13" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('13')";></span><span class="org_qty">4</span><span class="org_partno">ICS775</span><span class="org_desc">INSUL CABLE RACK 1.5"STG 7.75"</span></li>
<li id="il14" class="ui-state-default"><span id="add_hl14" class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line" onClick="addMLRow('14')";></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">ESD1080740001</span><span class="org_desc">ESD BANANA JACK</span></li>

</ul>
```

As you can see by the onClick function in each "li", I want to be anle to click a small button to the left of the line and insert a new blank line in that space while renumbering the items after it. The addMLRow() function will always pass where the item is in the list, as will the id of the line that contains the small button.

The jQuery UI already has a function to create an array of the list of items once it's complete, so I can pass back the data to a db and have position numbers, even for the black lines.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your solution did not work, as it also makes each of the added lines clickable to create a line above it. The header lines added with the onClick are of a different format as you can see by the snippet below:

```
function addMLRow(rowNo) {
    var newRow = "<li id=\'li" + rowNo + "\' class=\'ui-state-default\'><span class=\'item\'>HL</span><input class=\'header_line\' maxlength=\'75\' type=\'text\' name=\'hl_text[" + rowNo + "]\' id=\'hl_text" + rowNo + "\' /></li>";
    $('#ml_organize li:eq(' + (rowNo - 1) + ')').before(newRow);
    $('#hl_text' + rowNo + '').focus(function() {
        $(this).css('background','#DDD');
    });
    $('#hl_text' + rowNo + '').blur(function() {
        $(this).css('background','#FFF');
    });
    $('#hl_text' + rowNo + '').focus();
    // renumber rows after insert
    $('#ml_organize li:gt(' + (rowNo - 1) + ')').each(function() {
        var newID = 'li' + ($(this).index() + 1);
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
    });
}
```

Probably still not the most elegant solution but it works!

Comment: I see... if you don't want the newly added li's to be clickable, you can just change .live() to .bind()... the rest is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your span and li ids don't match up. Is that intentional?

Either way, you don't need all the span IDs and individual onClicks.

The following will insert a blank line before any LI (including blank LIs) whenever they are clicked, without the need for any onClicks.

```
$('#ml_organize li').live('click', function() {
    $(this).before('<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">0</span><span class="org_partno"> </span><span class="org_desc"> </span></li>');

});
```

I'd also look at simplifying the markup -- all the repeated classes seem a bit wasteful when you could just use the parent class for CSS styling.

Comment: Yes, the mismatched span and li ids are intentional. The user will be adding header lines that are not considered a line item, just a place holder.
Very elegant solution to the wasted onClick codes. I'm fairly new to jQuery and haven't yet mastered all the convenient places it can be used.
The add line is working excellently and I have figured out how to renaming subsequent li ids after the add... now I'm working on deleting the newly added line and renaming li ids again.
Thanks!